# How to call jquery-ui before bootstrap in a meteor project in order to prevent conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, meteor

I have a meteor project (I run it `mrt --release 0.6.5.1`). In this project I'm using `bootstrap2.3` and `jquery-ui 1.9.2` However since they're conflict, they're not working well. So as I can [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6887) it is recommended that :

> you should call always jquery-ui before bootstrap, if not you will see
>   a lot of problems like tooltips and so on.

Now, I have added bootstrap package into my meteor by using

```
meteor add bootstrap
   mrt add bootstrap
```

and I've added jquery-ui.js (downloaded  from [here](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js)) into `client/lib` and now it seems they're conflicting. What should I do so that jquery-ui will be loaded before bootstrap?

I've found my bootstrap version by using **chrome->developer->sources->packages**

this is my `projectFolder/smart.json` file in meteor project.

```
{
  "packages": {
    "router": {},
    "datatables": {},
    "select2": {},
    "accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown": {},
    "font-awesome": {},
    "verbalExpressions": {},
    "jquery-scrollTo": {},
    "bootboxjs": {},
    "event-hooks": {},
    "moment": {}
  }
}
```

And finally, this is my **.meteor/packages** file :

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

standard-app-packages
autopublish
insecure
preserve-inputs
accounts-base
accounts-password
router
event-hooks
bootstrap
accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown
moment
datatables
select2
jquery-scrollTo
verbalExpressions
http
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing bootstrap-3 and jquery-ui as packages using `meteor add` instead of trying to manually place the jquery-ui js file into client/ or lib/

**Bootstrap:**

```
$ meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

**Bootstrap-3** (*instead of* Bootstrap, not in addition):

```
$ meteor add ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
```

**jquery-ui:**

```
$ meteor add mizzao:jquery-ui
```

Almost everything you'll ever need in terms of packages can be found on [atmospherejs](https://atmospherejs.com/).

Comment: I'm continuing with an existing project and it is based on boostrap 2.3 . So I have no chance to replace it with bs3. Do you have a suggestion based on this information?

Comment: Then just use that first one `$ meteor add twbs:bootstrap`

Comment: in this way, I'll continue to use bootstrap2.3 and prevent from conflict ? Do I need to remove first current bootstrapt and remove lib/jquery-ui file?

Comment: You can keep your current bootstrap package, remove you jquery-ui, then add mizzao:jquery-ui.